# why Concurrency control uses the classic two-condition algorithm

Tags: concurrency, java

While reading the source code of `ArrayBlockingQueue`, I found a comment explaining that it uses "*the classic two-condition algorithm found in any textbook*":

```
/*
 * Concurrency control uses the classic two-condition algorithm
 * found in any textbook.
 */

/** Main lock guarding all access */
private final ReentrantLock lock;
/** Condition for waiting takes */
private final Condition notEmpty;
/** Condition for waiting puts */
private final Condition notFull;
```

Why does it use the classic two-condition (notEmpty, notFull) algorithm?

Comment: It enables to only wake threads interested in whatever just happened. For example, a thread trying to `take` from an empty queue, is only interested in the queue being not empty (there is something to take), but does not care about the queue not being full.

Comment: This is a nice *answer* :)

Comment: Your question suggests that you don't agree with or don't understand the author's decision. What other approach do you know of that he could have chosen instead?

Answer (score 3):

You already had a good comment. Only as a complement.

*ArrayBlockingQueue* is a *State-Dependent* class. This means that this class has operations that only can be performed with some preconditions.

The writer threads will only wait if the precondition (notFull) is false.

*// If the queue is full then writer needs to wait. 

// Atomically releases the lock and waits for the signal (notFull.signal() fired by a reader).* 
 
**while (count == items.length)

   notFull.await();**

For readers the concept is identical, but using the notEmpty condition.

*// If the queue is empty then reader needs to wait. 

// Atomically releases the lock and waits for the signal (notEmpty.signal() fired by a writter).* 
 
**while (count == 0)

   notEmpty.await();**

When a thread wakes up then you need 2 main things:
 
1 - Get the lock
 
2 - Re-Test the condition